# windows asking for format after unlocking bitlocker driver

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, encryption, bitlocker

I have internal 2TB hdd encrypted with bitlocker for almost 5 years, I have been using for just backup

I did a restart and after unlocking and try to open it, the windows tells me the drive is not formatted and I must format it first before using it !!!

If i press cancel another message comes after that telling me the driver is not accessible and the volume doesn't contain a recognized file system

I am using windows 8.1 ultimate

how can fix this problem ?

Comment: You can't.  It sound like the drive has failed and the required Bitlocker header is missing.

Comment: I can actually unlock the drive the windows is accepting my password and it shows the unlocked lock icon on the drive

Comment: If it is asking you to format the drive, the drive still has failed, a healthy working HDD does not out of the blue lose its filesystem.

Comment: can I do unformat or recovery !!

Comment: Recovery from your backup and doing a format on a broken HDD won't fix the HDD, it will make it so you can use it, until the HDD fail completely.  I cannot recommend you do that for obvious reasons.  You should replace the drive and restore your backup to that drive.

Comment: I am planning on doing this anyway I just need to know how to recover the files from the failed bitlocker drive !

Comment: Once successfully mounted you should be able to recover the data using the file recovery program of your choice.

Comment: You say the drive has just been used for backups - if so, you still have the original files on the live/main drives. I'd replace the broken backup drive with a new drive and carry on making backups to the new drive.

Answer (score -1):

From what I have found after a decent research for a solution for my problem I would recommend doing the following:

1. get a new drive with the same size or bigger
2. use [repair-bde](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829851.aspx) tool to recover the data which in my case saved 100% of the actual data on the 2TB HDD

that was the most efficient way for solving the problem, after that I have formatted the HDD and it is now working without any problems !!!